# How to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\arg (z_n) = \arg (z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> We know that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n = z_0$$
>   means $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x_0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = y_0$, 
>   But how to prove that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\arg(z_n)=\arg(z_0)$$

When we only know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n = z_0$.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of $\arg$ you use?

Comment: @dxiv arg means argument of complex number and  0 <= $arg(z_n)$ < 2pi

Comment: @FengyiYuan With that definition, the limit doesn't necessarily exist when $z_0$ is on the positive real axis. Consider for example $z_n=1 + i \cdot (-1)^n/n\,$.

Comment: @Derivative arctan function is continuous

Comment: @dxiv sorry, I dont understand. $z_n = 1 + i x (-1)^n / n$ , $\lim arg(z_n) = \lim arctan(i x (-1)^n / n)  = 0 = arg( z_0 )$

Comment: The even terms $z_{2n}=1+i/{2n}$ all lie in the $1^{st}$ quadrant, so $\arg(z_{2n}) \in (0, \pi/2)$. The odd terms $z_{2n+1}=1-i/{(2n+1)}$ all lie in the $4^{th}$ quadrant, so $\arg(z_{2n+1}) \in (3 \pi /2, 2 \pi)\,$. Therefore, the two subsequences cannot possibly have the same limit. In fact, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \arg(z_{2n})=0\,$ while $\lim_{n \to \infty} \arg(z_{2n+1})=2 \pi\,$.

Comment: You can't prove it because you cannot define arg(z) in such  a way that it is continuous at every z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $z_0 \neq 0$ and away from the branch cut. Take $z_n = r_ne^{i \theta_n}$ and $z_0 = r_0e^{i \theta_0},$ where $\theta_n = \arg (z_n)$ and $\theta_0 = \arg (z_0)$ are principal value arguments.

Suppose $|z_n - z_0| < \delta.$ In this case, $z_n$ is in a disk of radius $\delta$ with center $z_0$. Using some geometry we find

$$|\theta_n - \theta_0| \leqslant \arcsin \frac{\delta}{r_0}.$$

Look at a disk with center $z_0$ and radius $δ.$ The largest deviation in $|θ_n−θ_0|$ occurs at two points on the bounding circle where the ray with angle $θ_n$ emanating from the origin is tangent. We have a right triangle with hypoteneuse $r_0$ and side $δ.$ Hence, the included angle has sine equal to $δ/r_0.$

For any $\epsilon > 0$, choose  $\delta < r_0 \sin  \epsilon.$

Then $|z_n - z_0| < \delta$ implies $| \theta_n - \theta_0| < \epsilon,$ and since $z_n \to z_0,$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \arg(z_n) = \arg(z_0).$$

This fails to converge at $z_0 = 0$,  since $\theta_n$ can assume non-zero values in any neighborhood regardless of the magnitude of $|z_n - 0| = r.$

Comment: `and away from any branch cut` I think you should make the point more clear that your answer does *not* mean that $\,\arg(z_n)\,$ *always* converges, since that appears to be one case the OP had difficulty with, based on some previous comments.

Comment: @dxiv:  You are absolutely correct. If the sequence originates in a neighborhood of $z_0$ and we are using say principal values for $\arg z_n$ and $\arg z_0$ then this would work. If $z_n$ crosses a branch cut then, of course, there is a problem.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you very much.